# MySQL - Calculate percentage and count number of related records

Tags: mysql, sql, count, average

Please need help to complete the code to do the followin:

Calculate the number of votes and percentages of specific records, is a site of movies, where users can view and vote movies, then the website should show all films more to lower the number of votes by users, here the details of what I'm trying to do.

**1)** Calculate the number of votes in general each film.

**2)** Get the number of votes by separate "They are altogether 3 **table[votes]**" for each movie, such as:

Movie 1 There have been a total of 100 votes, 20% of users seemed **Regular**, 30% of users seemed **Good** and 50% of users seemed **Very good**.

**3)** Get the percentage of the maximum number of votes between "3 of table [votes]", if users voted more for the film was very good, I have to calculate the percentage of that, so we can create a small donut or graphic, showing movies and casts more than you liked to users, for example:

The film was voted Movie 1, with a total of 450 votes, which accounts for 50% of all votes received by user rating.

**So far I have done this:**

```
SELECT
    M.name AS title_movie,
    M.year AS premiere,
    G.name AS gender,
    COUNT(MHR.vote_id) AS total_voting_movie
FROM movies M
LEFT JOIN gender G ON M.gender_id = G.id
LEFT JOIN movies_has_rating MHR ON M.id = MHR.movie_id
GROUP BY M.id
ORDER BY M.id DESC
```

**Graphic tables database:**

[image]

**The complete code for the entire database:**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for gender
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `gender`;
CREATE TABLE `gender` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of gender
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `gender` VALUES ('1', 'Action');
INSERT INTO `gender` VALUES ('2', 'Musical');
INSERT INTO `gender` VALUES ('3', 'Sci Fi');

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for movies
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `movies`;
CREATE TABLE `movies` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of movies
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `movies` VALUES ('1', 'Alien', '1979', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies` VALUES ('2', 'Aliens', '1986', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies` VALUES ('3', 'Moulin Rouge', '2001', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies` VALUES ('4', 'Guys and Dolls', '1955', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies` VALUES ('5', 'Mama Mia', '1970', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies` VALUES ('6', 'Starman', '1984', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies` VALUES ('7', 'Tron', '1982', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies` VALUES ('8', 'The Matrix', '1988', '2');

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for movies_has_rating
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `movies_has_rating`;
CREATE TABLE `movies_has_rating` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `movie_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vote_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=156 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of movies_has_rating
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('1', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('2', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('3', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('4', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('5', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('6', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('7', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('8', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('9', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('10', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('11', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('12', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('13', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('14', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('15', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('16', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('17', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('18', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('19', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('20', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('21', '1', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('22', '1', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('23', '1', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('24', '1', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('25', '1', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('26', '1', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('27', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('28', '1', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('29', '1', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('30', '1', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('31', '1', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('32', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('33', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('34', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('35', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('36', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('37', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('38', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('39', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('40', '1', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('41', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('42', '1', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('43', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('44', '2', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('45', '2', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('46', '2', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('47', '2', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('48', '2', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('49', '2', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('50', '2', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('51', '2', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('52', '2', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('53', '2', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('54', '2', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('55', '2', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('56', '2', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('57', '2', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('58', '2', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('59', '2', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('60', '2', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('61', '2', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('62', '2', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('63', '2', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('64', '2', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('65', '2', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('66', '2', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('67', '2', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('68', '2', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('69', '2', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('70', '2', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('71', '2', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('72', '2', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('73', '2', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('74', '2', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('75', '2', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('76', '2', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('77', '2', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('78', '2', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('79', '2', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('80', '2', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('81', '2', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('82', '2', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('83', '2', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('84', '2', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('85', '3', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('86', '3', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('87', '3', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('88', '3', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('89', '3', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('90', '3', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('91', '4', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('92', '4', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('93', '4', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('94', '4', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('95', '4', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('96', '4', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('97', '4', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('98', '4', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('99', '4', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('100', '4', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('101', '4', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('102', '4', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('103', '4', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('104', '4', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('105', '4', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('106', '4', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('107', '4', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('108', '4', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('109', '4', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('110', '4', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('111', '5', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('112', '5', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('113', '5', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('114', '5', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('115', '5', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('116', '5', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('117', '5', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('118', '5', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('119', '5', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('120', '5', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('121', '5', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('122', '5', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('123', '5', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('124', '6', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('125', '6', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('130', '8', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('131', '8', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('132', '8', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('133', '8', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('134', '8', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('135', '8', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('136', '8', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('137', '8', '1');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('138', '8', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('139', '8', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('140', '8', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('141', '8', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('142', '8', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('143', '8', '2');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('144', '8', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('145', '8', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('146', '8', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('147', '8', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('148', '8', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('149', '8', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('150', '8', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('151', '8', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('152', '8', '3');
INSERT INTO `movies_has_rating` VALUES ('153', '8', '3');

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for users
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of users
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES ('1', 'Name user 1', '1@1.com');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES ('2', 'Name user 2', '2@2.com');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES ('3', 'Name user 3', '3@3.com');

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for votes
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `votes`;
CREATE TABLE `votes` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of votes
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `votes` VALUES ('1', 'Very good');
INSERT INTO `votes` VALUES ('2', 'Good');
INSERT INTO `votes` VALUES ('3', 'Regular');
```

*Much appreciate your support, thank you very much.*

Comment: Have you tried any code to calculate the percentage or are you asking help to complete the code for you?

Comment: @ Sajib Acharya - I'm trying to do this and I need to help me complete it, many others all forms thanks for the appreciation it shall specify at startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third part isn't clear. But the second part can be solved by:

```sql
SELECT
    M.name AS title_movie,
    M.year AS premiere,
    G.name AS gender,
    COUNT(MHR.vote_id) AS total_voting,
    -- 2)
    COUNT(MHR.vote_id = 1 OR NULL) AS count_very_good,
    COUNT(MHR.vote_id = 2 OR NULL) AS count_good,
    COUNT(MHR.vote_id = 3 OR NULL) AS count_regular
FROM movies M
LEFT JOIN gender G ON M.gender_id = G.id
LEFT JOIN movies_has_rating MHR ON M.id = MHR.movie_id
GROUP BY M.id
ORDER BY M.id DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ba403/5

I'm sure you know how to calculate the percentages from that result.

**Update:** So OP asks to determine the vote type with the highest count and calculate its percantage within SQL. You can (but you should not) do it with the folowing query:

```sql
SELECT t.*, 
    CASE
        WHEN highest_votes_id = 1
            THEN 100 * count_very_good / total_voting
        WHEN highest_votes_id = 2
            THEN 100 * count_good / total_voting
        WHEN highest_votes_id = 3
            THEN 100 * count_regular / total_voting
    END AS highest_votes_percentage
FROM (  
    SELECT t.*,
        CASE
            WHEN count_regular > count_good AND count_regular > count_very_good
                THEN 3
            WHEN count_good > count_very_good
                THEN 2
            ELSE 1
        END AS highest_votes_id
    FROM (
        SELECT
            M.id,
            M.name AS title_movie,
            M.year AS premiere,
            G.name AS gender,
            COUNT(MHR.vote_id) AS total_voting,
            COUNT(MHR.vote_id = 1 OR NULL) AS count_very_good,
            COUNT(MHR.vote_id = 2 OR NULL) AS count_good,
            COUNT(MHR.vote_id = 3 OR NULL) AS count_regular
        FROM movies M
        LEFT JOIN gender G ON M.gender_id = G.id
        LEFT JOIN movies_has_rating MHR ON M.id = MHR.movie_id
        GROUP BY M.id
    ) t
) t
ORDER BY t.id DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ba403/7

How ever you solve that problem in SQL, you will end up with unreasonable ugly code. You better do it in PHP.

```sql
if ($row['count_regular'] > $row['count_good'] &&
    $row['count_regular'] > $row['count_very_good']
) {
    $highestVoteType  = 'Regular';
    $highestVoteCount = $row['count_regular'];
} elseif ($row['count_good'] > $row['count_very_good']) {
    $highestVoteType  = 'Good';
    $highestVoteCount = $row['count_good'];
} else {
    $highestVoteType  = 'Very Good';
    $highestVoteCount = $row['count_very_good'];
}
if ($row['total_voting'] != 0) {
    $highestVotePercantage = 100 * $highestVoteCount / $row['total_voting'];
} else {
    $highestVotePercantage = null;
}
```

Comment: @ Paul Spiegel Thank you very much for answering :), works perfectly, a question, and I can take a percentage of 100% count_very_good, count_good and count_regular and percentages give me a hundred 100% with the calculated sum of porcetage between these types of votes

Comment: @ Paul Spiegel  Please help me with one more thing. 1) Get the maximum percentage of the vote, To obtain this result for example: Movie 1 There have been a total of 100 votes, 20% of users seemed Regular, 30% of users seemed Good and 50% of users seemed Very good.

Comment: I'm afraid i don't get your problem. To calculate the percantage of very-good-votes: percentage_very_good = 100 * count_very_good / total_voting.

Comment: I think I have not given to explain well, I want to make an additional calculation to what we have done, explain in point 3, I need to calculate the percentage of the vote but with the highest value of valuations, for example if the most users find it very good the movie, then that would calculate the percentage, but doing this from mysql, mysql that through us to verify the highest value of voting and from there calculate the percentage.

Comment: Let's see if i understand correctly: There are 100 votes of total for movie "Matrix". 50 votes are "very good", 30 votes are "good" and 20 votes are "regular". The vote type with highest value is "very good" wich is 50% of total votes. Now you want two additional columns: `highest_vote_type = 'very good'` and `highest_vote_percentage = 50`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, practically get is the highest percentage since one transaction in MySQL, and don't this with PHP, in this case would Very good, want an additional 3 columns showing the percentage of the highest vote, the ID and name highest vote "id=1 name=Very good", this obtain information from the table[votes], but I want to know if this can be done from Mysql, identify the highest value and then take a percentage, for example: COUNT(MAX(MHR.vote_id)) / total_voting * 100 AS highest_vote_percentage (INNER table[votes] name and id)

Comment: @ Paul Spiegel - Many thanks for your help, this works perfectly, you are a pro at this, I am very grateful for your help, if I could give you more points if you would any doubt, if you know how to use this http://stackoverflow.com/jobs, let me know, please send me a private, I wish you a great day and lots of luck and work s for you.

Answer (score 0):

1)

Select movies_has_rating.movie_id,movies.name,count(movies_has_rating.vote_id) FROM movies_has_rating JOIN movies ON movies_has_rating.movied_id=movies.id

Comment: @ Kilian Hertel - Thank you very much for responding, but that you're doing think it is made in the description have left a codebase, we can take it as a reference to what I stated in the beginning.